# Java - how to add panel in bottom-to-top order?

Tags: java, swing

Is there any way that I could add panels in bottom-to-top order?..

I've tried some layout managers, but still i couldn't get it..
need help.

> JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel(); 
> JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel(); 
> JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
> JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
>
> mainpanel.add(panel_1);
> mainpanel.add(panel_2);
> mainpanel.add(panel_3);
> mainpanel.add(panel_4);
> mainpanel.add(panel_5);
> mainpanel.add(panel_n);

[image: panels]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to specify an index for adding the panel. Ie:

```
mainpanel.add(panel_1, 0);
mainpanel.add(panel_2, 0);
mainpanel.add(panel_3, 0);
```

This will always add each panel in the first position.

Answer (score 1):

MigLayout works here as well - and increases maintainabilty:

```
JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout();

private void addPanel(JPanel newPanel) {
   mainpanel.add(newPanel, "dock north");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the panel in order, In which order you want to display in the frame.
Let p1,p2,p3 are the subv-panels and p is main panel.
You want order of panel as folowing : p2,p3,p1
    p.add(p2);
    p.add(p3);
    p.add(p1);
then finally add it to your frame.
I think this will help you.